# Sql query to skip a letter from set whenever its appear

Tags: sql

I have two set of data like {1,2,3,4} and {2,3,4,5}

How to write a sql query to get data like {1,2} and {2} means whenever 3 comes in the set it will skip the remaining part of the set.

Can anyone pls help me to get that query solved ??

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Is `{1,2,3,4}` a single (array) value? Or should that represent multiple _rows_ with a single column? Do you have another table that contains the `{2,3,4,5}` value? It's usually easier to represent sample data as a table (the way your SQL client displays it) using [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. Including `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question also helps